# FreeRadius Reading attributes while executing external script

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, freeradius

Can someone give me a hint, how to modify Freeradius to read other attributes from an external script.

I have this

```
update control {
        Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -f /web/auth.php '%{NAS-Identifier} %{Calling-Station-Id}'`
    }
```

But the reply right now can be **only**  Access or Reject , but I would like to set also some attributes more like a bandwidth limitation to this user like

**output**

```
Accept
WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up: xxx
WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down: xxx
WISPr-Redirection-URL: http://google.com
```

I can achieve this ?

System: Ubuntu 14.04

radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 2.2.5, for host x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, built on Aug  6 2014 at 15:08:48

**update**

How about `preacct` and `accounting` section ? I see that once router is rebooted it must keep Calling Station in "mind" and re-authenticate it once it will boot.
It is possible to add

```
accounting {
    exec
    update control {
        Auth-Type := "%{reply:Auth-Type}"
    }
    ...
}
```

there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, that's not valid syntax for version 2. You need to modify `raddb/modules/exec` and call it in the authorize section.

**Version 2**

For the exec module configuration you want:

```
wait = yes
program = "/usr/bin/php -f /web/auth.php '%{NAS-Identifier} %{Calling-Station-Id}'"
output_pairs = reply
```

Then in authorize:

```
authorize {
    exec
    update control {
        Auth-Type := "%{reply:Auth-Type}"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then modify your script output to be:

```
Auth-Type = Accept
WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up = xxx
WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down = xxx
WISPr-Redirection-URL = http://google.com
```

**Version 3**

Version 3 supports attribute assignment similar to what you've posted, but it'd be:

```
update {
    control: += `/usr/bin/php -f /web/auth.php '%{NAS-Identifier} %{Calling-Station-Id}'`
}
```

Then modify your script output to be:

```
Auth-Type = Accept
reply:WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up = xxx
reply:WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down = xxx
reply:WISPr-Redirection-URL = http://google.com
```

Comment: Check my post again, how about preacct and accounting ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with accounting

Comment: Hi again, I came with another question about radiusd, I'm trying to do an authentication from ChilliSpot and CoovaChilli to Radiusd which is running on Ubuntu right now, I saw that there are different parameters of auth like chillispot works with Auth-Type Accept or Reject, and CoovaChili with Auth: 0 or 1. THe problem is that I've tried both variants and I still cannot authenticate with coovachilli. Do you know anything about this ?

Comment: It's not usually appropriate to ask additional questions in comments, I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: ok, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288925/coovachilli-authentication